# undefined method or my Active Record mistakes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Sorry if my problem will be silly but Rails are new to me. I made two models and two controllers. My problems were started after I made second model and added reference to the first one.

```
class SentencesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_story

    def create      
        @sentence = find_story.sentences.build(sentence_params)
        if @sentence.save
           flash[:success] = "You wrote the continuation!"
           render 'stories/show'
        else
          render 'stories/show'
        end
    end

  private

    def sentence_params
      params.require(:sentence).permit(:content)
    end

    def find_story
        @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

and this:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController 

........

    def show
        @story = Story.find(params[:id])
        @sentence = @story.sentences.build
    end 

.........


end
```

And I have a problem with defining instance variable @story = Story.find(params[:id]). Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SentencesController#create. I have tried many combinations.

This is my migrate files:

```
class CreateStories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :stories do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSentences < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :sentences do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.references :story, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :sentences, [:story_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

What did I do wrong?

EDIT (routes):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'stories#index'
    get 'stories/show'
  get 'stories/new'
  resources :stories
  resources :sentences, only: [:create]
end
```

and schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180322121215) do

  create_table "sentences", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "story_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["story_id"], name: "index_sentences_on_story_id"
  end

  create_table "stories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb file (in your config folder). By convention, the id you're getting from `params[:id]` in the Sentences controller would likely be the id for the Sentence, not the Story.

Comment: `Story.find(params[:id])` raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error when a record is not found with the given `id`. So, you don't have a `Story` record with `params[:id]`, I suppose. Is it `params[:story_id]`, perhaps (if you have nested routes)? You might want to add your params to your question.

Comment: I added routes and schema.

Comment: My guess is your route is incorrect.  the route should have an id in it like this `stories/show/:id` where `:id` is the number id of the story.  Is that what the url looks like when it gives you this error or is it just `stories/show` ?

Comment: `@RockwellRice` When I used `stories/show/:id` I cannot even open Story record, so it made it worse. The idea is that I want to add the sentences to the specific Story. So I can open Story record (it has id=1) but when I put text in text_area and click submit button `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` shows up.

Comment: The `params[:id]` in your `SentencesController` is going to be a *sentence* ID if it exists at all. Perhaps you want to look at nesting the `resources :sentences, only: [:create]` inside the `resources :stories` so that you can get the story ID through `params[:story_id]`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you probably want your routes to look something like:

```
resources :stories do 
  resources :sentences, only: [:create]
end
```

Which will give you:

```
 story_sentences POST   /stories/:story_id/sentences(.:format)   sentences#create
         stories GET    /stories(.:format)                       stories#index
                 POST   /stories(.:format)                       stories#create
       new_story GET    /stories/new(.:format)                   stories#new
      edit_story GET    /stories/:id/edit(.:format)              stories#edit
           story GET    /stories/:id(.:format)                   stories#show
                 PATCH  /stories/:id(.:format)                   stories#update
                 PUT    /stories/:id(.:format)                   stories#update
                 DELETE /stories/:id(.:format)                   stories#destroy
```

Which you might use something like:

```
<%= form_tag story_sentences_path(@story) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then, as Matt said, change your `find` to:

```
@story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Routing is much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasonable ways you can find the story in your sentences controller.

1. You can add a `story_id` field to your form and submit it as a param along with the sentence content. Just make sure to add it to `sentence_params` in the controller so it's not ignored.

   ```
   def sentence_params
     params.require(:sentence).permit(:content, :story_id)
   end
   ```

   And then you'll need to update your find_story method in the controller to:

   ```
   @story = Story.find(sentence_params[:story_id])
   ```
2. You can set up nested resources in your routes file (where the sentences resource is nested within the stories resource). That will give you access to the `story_id` from the route itself (ie. you wouldn't need to submit the `story_id` through the form).

   And if you go this way, you'll also need to tweak the `find_story` method in the controller, but this time it should be:

   ```
   @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did your second way. And now I'm trying to do the first one. How can I add it to `sentence_params` in the controller? I did hidden field in the view but I don't how to write it in the controller.

Comment: I'll add a better code example for the first option in my answer. But out of curiosity, was the second way not working for you? Or you just decided not to go with nested resources for other reasons?

Comment: Nesting is fine for me but I wondered how nesting will work, if there will be more models with many references, so I wanted to check your first idea to better understand Rails. Thanks!