# submit using hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My problem is connected with my [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438892/undefined-method-or-my-active-record-mistakes/49440228#49440228). It was solved by using nested routing. But there was different idea without using nested resources. I tried it as an exercise. But when I submit data, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SentencesController#create` shows up.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'stories#index'
    get 'stories/show'
  get 'stories/new'
  post 'stories/:story_id', to: 'sentences#create'
  resources :stories
  resources :sentences, only: [:create] 
end
```

shared/_sentence_form.html.erb is part of story/show_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@sentence) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :story_id, value: @story.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new sentence..." %>
  <%= f.submit "Save"%>
<% end %>
```

SentencesController

```
class SentencesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :sentence_params
    before_action :find_story

    def create
        @sentence = find_story.sentences.build(sentence_params)
    if @sentence.save
      flash[:success] = "You wrote the continuation!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
        flash[:danger] = "I did not save your words!"
        redirect_to "#"
    end
  end

  private

    def sentence_params
      params.permit(:content, :story_id)
    end

    def find_story
        @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    end
end
```

and model:

```
class Sentence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :story
  validates :story_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
end
```

I tried many combinations in controller and view. When I put some information in the text_area and click submit they don't save.

Comment: What do your submitted params look like? Perhaps this: `hidden_field_tag :story_id, value: @story.id` should be this: `hidden_field_tag :story_id, @story.id`

Comment: I don't really see why you're trying the worst possible way to solve the problem though when you already have an answer which shows the rails way to handle it gracefully.

Comment: `@max` As I wrote this is an exercise. I'm Rails beginner and I'm experimenting a bit to get along with Ruby (on Rails). Thanks for advice to keep REST designing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The param is nested:

```
def find_story
  @story = Story.find(params[:sentance][:story_id])
end
```

But nesting the route is a better RESTful design anyways.

The route `POST /stories/:story_id/sentances` makes it very clear what the action does.

```
resources :stories do
  resources :sentences, only: [:create] 
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for([@story, @sentence]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new sentence..." %>
  <%= f.submit "Save"%>
<% end %>
```

This will properly pass `params[:story_id]` as a segment of the URL.

Comment: In rails 5 `validates :story_id, presence: true` is totally superflous as `belongs_to` associations are non-optional by default.

Comment: I'd say the `hidden_field_tag` is superfluous in the form, since the `story_id` is already given in the url, right?

Comment: @HolgerFrohloff, yes it was just a copy-paste omission.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that's a solution to your problem, but I believe that

```
def sentence_params
  params.permit(:content, :story_id)
end
```

needs a `:sentence` in there somewhere. Your form is a `form_for @sentence` so I guess your params are `params[:sentence][:content]` or similar.

I believe your error happens in the line `@story = Story.find(params[:story_id])`, right? Make sure that the `@story` variable is present in your form and that the record can be found.